Which French keyboard is my Ubuntu 22.04 using
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and an AZERTY keyboard. I wish to modify the keyboard layout currently and make my own customized keyboard, either to have combinations to currently unavailable characters or to have combinations which I find more convenient for already available characters.
Specifically, on the keyboard of my dreams (which by the way I was able to construct on my Mac before I switched to Ubuntu) I want the following :

A modifier key corresponding to each accent among  '(acute),`(grave),~(tilde), which should be appliable to all vowels (and a few consonants, such as Spanish "n" with tilde) and compatible with "shift" (capitalization/uncapitalization).
A key combination for the French "guillemot" characters « and » (there already is a key combination for guillemots on my current layout, but I find it unintuitive, hard to remember and wish to change it).
A key combination for the Spanish "inverted question mark" character.

In Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources, the selected keyboard layout is called "French" :

I presume that this means that the keyboard is defined in  file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr. So I looked up this file with the intent of making a copy of it and editing a few things here and there for my own purposes.
Now this fr file contains code for dozens of different variant keyboard layouts, and I have no idea which one is currently in use on my computer. How can I determine this ?
UPDATE: I have selected the "right-control" key as the "Compose" key (by default there was no key selected) :


ah ok, I think I get the gist of this now. Before doing anything make a backup of that file in case things go awry. Initially use nano -l /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr to view the file. That places line numbers alongside each line of code in the file. You will see that layouts begin ~line 94 and continue down the file. I think you might find this change keyboard layout of some use. If you intend to edit the file, use sudo nano of course. Not sure that this is entirely the right approach though and cause issues down the line.

For information (as a French resident but native English speaker) I use an English (UK) keyboard when typing French characters using the Compose key with another symbol to achieve chars such as á and ô etc. The compose key "latches" and then expects the next 2 chars to make the symbol appear in the app. I'm sure there are other similar combinations for Spanish chars too and you could add a SP keyboard layout for experimentation as a starting point rather than mess with the system.

ñ is available on my UK keyboard using the Compose key then n then ~.

@graham On my French AZERTY keyboard, Compose,n,- prints just -

are you pressing the keys together or in sequenceand which key have you selected as the compose key?

@graham I have selected the "Right-Ctrl" key to be the compose key, see the update in my question

has that now solved your issue? You may also be interested in the AltGr key https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key which can assist with other chars
